# Android Splash Activity

Tags: java, android-activity, splash-screen, android-bluetooth

I have question on Flash, How do I request user to enable bluetooth, wait for it and then continue with starting main activity if if user allows , or exit the app if the user denies, I have following code in my app

```
// Library from Android
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

// User defined library
import java.io.IOException;

import eu.atriaparis.support.ATRIAExceptions.BluetoothDeviceException;
import eu.atriaparis.support.R;
import eu.atriaparis.ledplayfinal.MainControllerActivity;


// Starting Splash Activity for loading other background process. before main.
// Edited Harsha S, for ATRIA Paris - 2015
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private static String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getName();
    private static long SLEEP_TIME = 3;                         //Max Loading Time
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 22;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        // Start timer and launch main activity
        IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
        launcher.start();

        // Wait for the launcher thread to complete.

    }

//    @Override
//    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//        Log.d(TAG,"onActivityResult");
//        switch (requestCode) {
//            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
//                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
//                    // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
//                    finish();
//                }
//                break;
//            default:
//                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//                break;
//        }
//    }

    // Internal Class which loads all the other background activity and then starts main thread.
    // ATRIA Paris - 2015
    private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {

        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private int progressStatus = 0;

        @Override
        /**
         * Sleep for some time and than start new activity.
         */
        public void run() {

            // Progress
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

            // Network
            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            // For Error Handling
            BluetoothDeviceException exception;


            try {

                // Status 1, Check device and bluetooth status
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000/3);
                progressStatus = 20;
                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                // Status 2, Check Network Status
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.BluetoothAdapterNotFound), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000/3);
                    throw new BluetoothDeviceException("Bluetooth Module Not Found");
                }
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000/3);
                    Log.d("Splash", "Bluetooth Status + "+ mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled());
                }
                progressStatus = 50;
                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                // Status 3
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000/3);
                progressStatus = 75;
                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                // Final Activity
                // Load background activities
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000/3);
                progressStatus = 100;
                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                // Start main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainControllerActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "on Flash"?

Comment: like loading screen or start up screen,

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? What have you tried, what does not work?

Comment: In most of the modern app when they start they have loading screen(splash activity), Its been a while i worked on this project but when user starts our application, he lands on splash screen(loading screen), then we have few thihings done in background and then enters the main activity, I dont know how to control this action, i can start an activity splash (loading activity) after this applications goes to main activity even if there is some problem with loading.

Comment: In the above activity for example i have background things like checking the network, bluetooth etc etc which is required by our application, if the user doesnot have this turned on the application should stop at splash/loding activity, but it wont it lands to main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code its normal you always land in the main activity. There is no logic to prevent this.
The code lines

`// Start main activity
       Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainControllerActivity.class);
       SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
       SplashActivity.this.finish();`

Is are always executed. You need to treat the unexpected behaviors and do the appropriate thing(whatever this is).